# How can I get a list of flutter text to speech and flutter speech to text supported voices or accents?

Tags: flutter, text-to-speech, speech-to-text

I can not find flutter text to speech and speech to text supported language voices(accents)

I wanna get a list of supported voices with their language and country codes

Answer (score 1):

Using the "Flutter TTS" package you can you the method:
flutterTts.getVoices to get a list of a voice map (name,locale).
And then use flutterTts.setVoice() to define which voice will be used.

THis way for example I use the locale (eg: en-us, pt-br), to filter only the voices of a given language and add them to a list of single string with name+locale, which I can then use for a combobox, for example.

```
String languagePrefix = _language.substring(0, 2).toLowerCase();
try {
  var voices = await flutterTts.getVoices;
  if (voices != null) {
    var castVoices = voices.map<Map<String, dynamic>>((voice) {
      return Map<String, dynamic>.from(voice as Map);
    }).toList();

    setState(() {
      _availableVoices = castVoices.where((voiceMap) {
        String locale = voiceMap['locale'].toString().toLowerCase();
        return locale.startsWith(languagePrefix);
      }).map<String>((voiceMap) {
        return "${voiceMap['name']} | ${voiceMap['locale']}";
      }).toList();
    });
  }
} on Exception catch (e) {
  print(e);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use flutter to get that text or voice record ad then you send this data to an API that do that job for you return text or what u want
google has paid on you can have 60 min for free